# onclick of a link Submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jsp, redirect, form-submit, tiles

I am working on a application where I am using tiles templates for display. In a screen, on left hand side I am displaying the links for navigating to other pages. on the right hand side I am displaying the content of the screen.

Both are from different JSP's. So I need to do a form submission from screen's content by clicking on that link. Please suggest any ideas for doing this, I am not even close get this idea on how to write a javaScript function for this case.

Comment: If you could also attach a picture. It would be quite helpful. Do more study on Ajax request. You have to make ajax request. You also have to have some idea on javascript, jQuery. Research and learn them to integrate with JSP.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, There are two ways in which you can send your form easily.

1. Write a event Handler and call `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();` where "myForm" is your form name.
2. Use jquery for the same. The code below can help if your form id is `target`. Here `other` refers to a button or link which you click.

   $( "#other" ).click(function() {
     $( "#target" ).submit();
   });

Comment: I need to submit the form onclick of a link on the lefthand side which is from anoher jsp. So I am no sure how can I integrate this. @Shiv Kumar